# Advice on which PostgreSQL indexes to use to search for text?

Tags: text, full-text-search, postgresql-9.5, text-search

I have some tables in scheme of PostgreSQL. I need to find text in some tables at the same time. I need find the same phrases in different tables and also different phrases in different tables. In the end I need to join this tables and give id from the main table. Which solution is the best? P.S. Tables will update frequently.

Comment: You should look at PostgreSQL's full text search features: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes. I have upgraded the  version.